# avrdude problem with sck , how to recover locked avr with external clock fuse bit

Tags: avr, atmega, programming, linux, avrdude

I wrote this code:

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1105920UL
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void){
    DDRC=0b00100000;
    while(1){
        PORTC=0b00100000;
        _delay_ms(5000);
        PORTC=0b00000000;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

I programed it in `atmega8`:

```
sudo avrdude -c usbasp -p m8 -U flash:w:my.hex
```

micro programed ,OK, not problem:

i wanted use external `crystal`; then i connected crystal `11.0592` to pin 10 and 9, and rewrite fuse bit:

```
sudo avrdude -c usbasp -p m8 -U lfuse:w:0xE0:m
```

`fuse bit` rewrite and OK.not problem

---

now i realized this value `1105920UL` is mistake, i edit code and change `1105920UL` to `11059200UL` ,

but when i programed micro, `avrdude` get me error:

```
$sudo avrdude  -c usbasp -p m8 -U flash:w:my.hex 

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

My micro is lock?
or i must rewire `sck`? 
how to i resolve this problem?!?

Thank you

Comment: Abstracting the crystal problem - the avrdude message about the SCK means that you have old usbasm firmware. Update it and you will be able to change the sck frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I programed another micro (`atmega16`) and use it from external clock,

```
$regfile = "m16def.dat"
$crystal = 8000000
Config Portd = Output

Do

Toggle Portd.1
Loop

End
```

Or in `codevision` (with internal rc `8Mhz`) :

```
while(1){
    PORTD.0 = ! PORTD.0
}
```

and connect `D0` pin (`atmega16`) to `xtal1` of locked micro (`atmega8`),

and now we can program locked micro and change fuse bit or set to default value.

---

`U1` is `atmega16` for use external clock

`U2` is `atmega8`, locked micro, and we want change it fuse bit

[image: imge]

---

thank from [@Janka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/376275/46812)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is lfuse:0xE0 means "external clock". You have to use an integrated 8 to 16MHz crystal oscillator and connect it to XTAL1. Your device should be reprogrammable again, at least.

To use a bare crystal, you need an lfuse setting of 0xEE. But you cannot change this now, you had to connect the external oscillator you had selected before first.

Comment: yes, i use external crystal `11.0592` and connect it to pin `9(XTAL1) and 10(XTAL2)` ,,but i can't re program my micro!

Comment: External clock != External crystal. Please read and understand pages 27, 32, and 217 of the ATmega8 datasheet. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwj244KZs5_bAhVOr6QKHc0IADgQFghDMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2Fatmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2kBMObMwJjMlZ9dmKLzNPM

Comment: you could use an Arduino to generate the clock signal

Comment: @jsotola how to do it?